# HTTP Error 404.3 - If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map

Tags: iis, mime-types

I am getting following error when I try to download pdf or excel files from my website . It works fine in my local m/c but when deployed on server it errors out.

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>   The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Application configuration are :
asp.net V4 website hosted on Windows WebServer 2008 v6 SP1 ,IIS 7.0.

Things that I've tried are:

1: Checking if asp.net is registered. Re registering ASP.NET using  aspnet_regiis-i and restarting IIS.
2:Checking if pdf and xls are added in MIME TYPES.

But I still get this error.

Comment: experts, any idea how to resolve this plz..

Comment: Still struggling to resolve this.. any help will be appreciated..